# Как переопределить класс woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress, php

Есть следующий код в файле `class-product-cat-dropdown-walker.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * WC_Product_Cat_Dropdown_Walker class.
 *
 * @extends     Walker
 * @class       WC_Product_Cat_Dropdown_Walker
 * @version     1.6.4
 * @package     WooCommerce/Classes/Walkers
 * @author      WooThemes
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

class WC_Product_Cat_Dropdown_Walker extends Walker {

    var $tree_type = 'category';
    var $db_fields = array ('parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'term_id', 'slug' => 'slug' );

    /**
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     * @since 2.1.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $category Category data object.
     * @param int $depth Depth of category in reference to parents.
     * @param integer $current_object_id
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $cat, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {

        if ( ! empty( $args['hierarchical'] ) )
            $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 3);
        else
            $pad = '';

        $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_product_cats', $cat->name, $cat );

        $value = isset( $args['value'] ) && $args['value'] == 'id' ? $cat->term_id : $cat->slug;

        $output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"" . $value . "\"";

        if ( $value == $args['selected'] || ( is_array( $args['selected'] ) && in_array( $value, $args['selected'] ) ) )
            $output .= ' selected="selected"';

        $output .= '>';

        $output .= $pad . __( $cat_name, 'woocommerce' );

        if ( ! empty( $args['show_count'] ) )
            $output .= '&nbsp;(' . $cat->count . ')';

        $output .= "</option>\n";
    }

    /**
     * Traverse elements to create list from elements.
     *
     * Display one element if the element doesn't have any children otherwise,
     * display the element and its children. Will only traverse up to the max
     * depth and no ignore elements under that depth. It is possible to set the
     * max depth to include all depths, see walk() method.
     *
     * This method shouldn't be called directly, use the walk() method instead.
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     *
     * @param object $element Data object
     * @param array $children_elements List of elements to continue traversing.
     * @param int $max_depth Max depth to traverse.
     * @param int $depth Depth of current element.
     * @param array $args
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @return null Null on failure with no changes to parameters.
     */
    public function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output ) {
        if ( ! $element || 0 === $element->count ) {
            return;
        }
        parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }   
}
```

Мне надо добавить дополнительный стиль в `select`. Хочу переопределить класс `WC_Product_Cat_Dropdown_Walker`, добавив нужный мне код (не изменяю сам `woocommerce` файл, чтобы при обновлении `woocommerce` он не накрылся). Не знаю, как это правильно сделать. В самом `functions.php` темы прописывать, чтобы он видел мои изменения, или как. Может, ссылки или информация есть, что почитать на эту тему. Но лучше живой пример на моем. ) Спасибо.

Comment: http://dev-city.me/2016/07/10/how-to-override-woocommerce-widget
Чтоб не копипастить всю статью, кидаю ссылку
Там все подробно расписали..